# Setting up Panda Wireless Wi-Fi on Raspberry PI before plugging it in

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, usb, raspberry-pi

I have a RPI zero and I've managed to get it to do SSH over USB with my computer.

I'd like to have it connect to the Internet, though, so I'd like to use my "PAU05" Panda wireless Wi-Fi dongle. The problem is, both SSH and Wi-Fi require the same USB port.

So I'm wondering if there's some way I can run a script at startup or something to automatically set up and connect to my Wi-Fi network. The goal of this would be:

1. SSH in and write the script and put it in the right place
2. Unplug the RPI zero
3. Plug in the Wi-Fi dongle to the USB port.
4. Start the RPI using its power port, and on boot it automatically sets up Panda Wireless and connects to the Internet
5. SSH in through my local network instead of through USB.

How can I do this? The main part I'm stuck on is that I have no idea what exactly is required to set up Panda Wireless on the RPI zero (i.e., don't know what to put in my startup script). Most guides say plug the RPI zero into a screen, but I don't have the right cables for that. Also, I'm using Jessie Lite, so I don't think it even has a screen. Anyone know the solution?

I have an Amazon USB hub with 4 ports as well as a few converters (USB to OTG and others), but I can't seem to get it to do SSH over USB with that.